# Is it possible to inject dependencies at compile time?

Tags: svelte

Is there a way to inject dependencies at compile time? Like by adding more `import` statements? 
Ideally, without impacting source maps.

Would like a folder structure like this:

```
+ pages
 + index.svelte
 + team.svelte
 + team.json <-- companion file
 + products.svelte
 + products.graphql <-- companion file
```

At compile time, would like to detect when a `.svelte` file has a companion file with the same base name (but with different extension like `.json`, `.graphql`, `.csv`, `.js`) and import it automatically.

I tried using `svelte.compile('<script>import ... </script>' + source)`, but you can only have one instance level `<script>` tag per file.

**Example code**:

```
compiler.compile("<script>import x from 'y'</script>\n<script>let x = 22</script>\n{x}")
```

**Error**:

```
Thrown:
A component can only have one instance-level <script> element (2:0)
1: <script>import x from 'y'</script>
2: <script>let x = 22</script>
   ^
3: {x}
```

Comment: I totally don't understand where you're going... But have you tried to add your import inside the existing `<script>` tag (if any)? If you write it all right hand side of an existing line, no existing code will be moved so sourcemap will be unaffected.

Comment: Good point, i will try that.